Are the eigenvalues of $ A = P D P^{-1} $ the diagonal entries of $ D $ and eigenvectors the columns of $ P $?
Suppose I have three vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ whose determinant is non-zero when used to form a matrix $ P $ by placing these vectors as columns. Then I define a diagonal matrix $ D $ with arbitrary entries on its main diagonal. Now I form the matrix $ A = P D P^{-1} $: this is the definition of diagonalizable matrix.
My question is: if I calculate the characteristic polynomial of $ A $, i.e., find the determinant of $ A - \lambda I $, will the roots (eigenvalues) of this polynomial be exactly the entries on the main diagonal of $ D $? Additionally, will the eigenvectors of $ A $ correspond to the columns of $ P $?
Thank you for any clarification on this question.

Should be yes...

Yes because you have $AP=PD,$  and that just says that $Ax=\lambda x$ for each diagonal entry/eigenvalue $\lambda $ and corresponding column of $P$/eigenvector $x.$
